# Making a piecewise function

Tags: python, arguments, piecewise

I'm trying to write the piecewise a simple piece wise function, yet it won't work when you put in a list.

```
# your code here
def pwfun(*args):
    
    for x in args:
        if x < -1:
            return(-2 * (x + 1))
        elif x > 1:
            return(x**2 - 1)
        else:
            return(0)
```

I thought that args would help out for any lists that I try, yet I keep getting the following error when I'm trying to run the code with a list of variables. I was wondering if there's an additional step with *args or I'm using *args wrong in the first place

```
<ipython-input-35-c95bcaddf037> in pwfun(*args)
      3 
      4     for x in args:
----> 5         if x < -1:
      6             return(-2 * (x + 1))
      7         elif x > 1:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: How are you calling `pwfun`? the error suggests that `x` is a list.

Comment: I'm writing x = [-6, 0 , 2] Then writing pwfun(x) on teh lien after

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that calling `pwfun(-6, 0, 1)` will assign `args` to `(-6, 0, 1)` but calling `pwfun([-6, 0, 1])` will assign `args` to `([6, 0, 1])` (notice double brackets).

To fix this (if you still want to use `*args`), I would do:

```py
pwfun(*x)
```

The `*x` means that `*args` is assigned to `(-6, 0, 1)` not `([-6, 0, 1])`.

If this isn't what you want, there are a few other ways:

1. Define `pwfun` like: `def pwfun(args):` so that `args` has the value `[6, 0, 1]`.
2. Just do `for x in args[0]`. This would mean that you iterate over the first argument of the function.

---

N.B.
As your program returns on the first iteration of the for loop, you don't need the for loop.

Comment: It worked for the test I did, but it's not working for the notebook tests the teacher assigned because there's no *x for her tests. Is there anything you suggest to get the function to work for pwfun(x)

Comment: @JosephSilva I edited my answer to include a few other ways. From what I understand, you're aloud to edit inside `pwfun`, but not the code which calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your solution – one in the way you call your function, one in the implementation of your function:

First, as already pointed out in [@sbottingota's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76107543/7395592), you are calling your function with a list, but your function signature and internal logic has been designed as if it should be called with individual values:

- If you have a list `x = [-6, 0, 2]` and call `pwfun(x)`, then your `args` looks as follows: `([1, 2, 3],)`; in other words, you will have your list of values wrapped inside a one-element tuple. As a consequence, when iterating over the values in `args` in your loop, you will get the list `[-6, 0, 2]` as the first and only value for your loop variable `x`, which ends in a comparison of a list (`[-6, 0, 2]`) with an integer (`-1`), which is undefined.
- If you call `pwfun(*x)` instead, with the same list `x`, this will be the same as calling `pwfun(-6, 0, 2)`, i.e. the same as calling your function with the individual elements of the list. Then `*args` will gather them into a new list (or rather, tuple), which will look as expected: `(-6, 0, 2)`. As a consequence, when iterating over `args` you will iterate over the individual values, as expected.

However (second issue), in your for-loop, you will return in each if-statement. This means that the loop will never reach any element after the first element in `args`, as you will have already exited both your loop and your function with returning the result for your first element only.

There are two solutions that I can think of for your problem: (1) gathering the results in a list again, (2) using a generator function. Let's have a look at the individual solutions in the following sections.

### Your solution

```py
def pwfun(*args):
    for x in args:
        if x < -1:
            return(-2 * (x + 1))
        elif x > 1:
            return(x**2 - 1)
        else:
            return(0)

x = [-6, 0, 2]
result = pwfun(*x)
print(f"Calling pwfun(*x) with x = {x}:")
print(f"The result is of type {type(result)} and looks as follows: {result}")
# >>> Calling pwfun(*x) with x = [-6, 0, 2]:
# >>> The result is of type <class 'int'> and looks as follows: 10
```

As you can see, the function only returns a result for the first value in `args`.

**Side note**: In python, `return` is a keyword, not a function or anything that is called; so while writing `return(0)` etc. works, you would normally write `return 0` without the brackets.

### Solution with result list

```py
def pwfun_list(*args):
    result = []
    for x in args:
        if x < -1:
            result.append(-2 * (x + 1))
        elif x > 1:
            result.append(x ** 2 - 1)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return result

x = [-6, 0, 2]
result = pwfun_list(*x)
print(f"Calling pwfun_list(*x) with x = {x}:")
print(f"The result is of type {type(result)} and looks as follows: {result}.")
print("The individual values are:")
for value in result:
    print(value)
# >>> Calling pwfun_list(*x) with x = [-6, 0, 2]:
# >>> The result is of type <class 'list'> and looks as follows: [10, 0, 3].
# >>> The individual values are:
# >>> 10
# >>> 0
# >>> 3
```

Here, we iterate over the values in `args`, but rather than returning results immediately, we append them to a new list `result`, which we return once, at the very end. As a result, we have evaluated the function for all values rather than only for the first one.

### Solution with generator

```py
def pwfun_gen(*args):
    for x in args:
        if x < -1:
            yield -2 * (x + 1)
        elif x > 1:
            yield x ** 2 - 1
        else:
            yield 0

x = [-6, 0, 2]  
result = pwfun_gen(*x)
print(f"Calling pwfun_gen(*x) with x = {x}:")
print(f"The result is of type {type(result)} and looks as follows: {result}.")
print("The individual values are:")
for value in result:
    print(value)
# >>> Calling pwfun_gen(*x) with x = [-6, 0, 2]:
# >>> The result is of type <class 'generator'> and looks as follows: <generator object pwfun_gen at 0x000001E8AE3787B0>.
# >>> The individual values are:
# >>> 10
# >>> 0
# >>> 3
```

This solution looks more similar to your original solution. However, as we replaced `return` with `yield`, we will get a *generator* in return when calling `pwfun_gen(*x)`.

The generator will then provide the result for each individual element in `args` (and not only for the first one), once we iterate over it with `for value in result`. In contrast to a list, however, this last step will work only once, and then the generator will be "exhausted".

The concept of generators is maybe a bit less intuitive than a regular Python function (at least that's what I think). You can find a good introduction [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), if you are interested.